# 20.10 to latest version KUBUNTU - How to?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu. my ubuntu version is 20.10 and I want to upgrade it to the latest version. How can I do it?

Comment: Follow the release instructions for where you want to go to, ie. 21.04.  https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/ will tell you to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HirsuteUpgrades/Kubuntu

Answer (score 2):

You are always best reading the release notes for the product you want to upgrade to.

Kubuntu's 21.04 release notes can be found at https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/

And that will tell you to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HirsuteUpgrades/Kubuntu

Any issues of concern the QA (*Quality Assurance*) testers found will be documented there, and along with the instructions the team QA-tested.

*Blogs and even sites like this maybe easier to read, but I'd always opt for the official instructions that were QA-tested by the team themselves.*

Comment: I could copy & paste instructions from the official site.. but I'm very much of the opinion you're best reading the official instructions  (we at Lubuntu use the same instructions ourselves for upgrade as LXQt is Qt5 based just like KDE is, but the *flavor* teams make a substantial effort in ensuring our instructions are as clear as we can make them and it's always where I'd look)